# Run each test case in a separate process successively (not in parallel) using pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, automation, pytest, testcase

can anyone help me, please?

I have 11 test cases in Python. These test cases check a function from a framework. The problem is that I cannot use this function more than once in a single test suite. I thought maybe I can run each test case in a separate process successively (not in parallel) because test cases are dependent on each other.

I tried this approach but it didn't work:

```
import multiprocessing

def test_case_1():
    # code
    pass

def test_case_2():
    # code
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_cases = [test_case_1, test_case_2]

    for test_case in test_cases:
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=test_case)
        process.start()
        process.join()
```

Answer (score -3):

The reason your current approach is not working as expected is that the `join()` method blocks until the process is finished, effectively waiting for the first test_case to complete before starting the next one. Since you want to run the test cases successively (not in parallel), you should not use the `multiprocessing` module, as it is designed for parallel processing.

Instead, you can simply call the test cases one after the other in a loop without any need for multiprocessing. The Python unittest framework provides a way to create test suites and run test cases in sequence. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```py
import unittest

def test_case_1():
    # code for test case 1
    pass

def test_case_2():
    # code for test case 2
    pass

class MyTestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case_1(self):
        test_case_1()

    def test_case_2(self):
        test_case_2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTestSuite)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

In this example, we create a test suite `MyTestSuite` that contains two test cases, `test_case_1` and `test_case_2`. The test cases are written as separate functions as you mentioned in your original code. The `unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)` will run the test cases in the order they are defined in the `MyTestSuite` class, one after the other, without the need for multiprocessing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, this code runs the test cases sequentially in the same process by default. It does not run test cases in separate processes.

Comment: @Sabrina this post was written by chatgpt.